# AngularJS - Not able to retrieve a json element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In my angular web app, I am trying to retrieve a json element (consolidationScopeId) but it prints as undefined.

```
$scope.consolidationScopeChanged = function(consolidationScope) {
console.log("consolidationScope : " +consolidationScope);
 console.log("consolidationScope : " +$scope.reportType.consolidationScope);
console.log("consolidationScope.consolidationScopeId : " +$scope.reportType.consolidationScope.consolidationScopeId);
```

}

I have logged it using console.log...

Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/CRypbp6AIXEAYbeJupoh?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please parse your json object.using JSON.parse

```js
  $scope.consolidationScopeChanged = function(consolidationScope) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(consolidationScope).frequencies);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You data is set as string in model.

Try like this

```
 console.log(JSON.parse(consolidationScope).frequencies);
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/2KSpV1zz5Yr35f1FiW2i?p=preview)**</kbd>

Instead use **[`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)** , he'll map things for you

Like this

```
<select id="Select2" class="form-control" ng-model="reportType.consolidationScopeCode" data-ng-options="conScopeFreqStartDates as conScopeFreqStartDates.consolidationScopeLabel  for conScopeFreqStartDates in conScopeFreqStartDates" ng-change="consolidationScopeChanged(reportType.consolidationScopeCode)">
      <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

JS

```
  $scope.consolidationScopeChanged = function(consolidationScope) {
    console.log(consolidationScope.frequencies);
  }
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/ss9XtpdNL2FerYIMzOID?p=preview)**</kbd>